# Language that can call C functions without binding code

Tags: programming-languages

In C and C++, I can include a header file from a library and call its functions directly without glue code. Are there any other languages that offer this feature? Perhaps a language which compiles to C could leave the `include` statement and all function calls intact, so that they would be correctly compiled and linked by the C compiler.

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly that you don't even want something like this: `ccall( (:clock, "libc"), Int32, ())`, to call C's `clock()` function? You just want to type `clock()`?

Comment: Correct, although that form is simpler than others I've seen. Is that Julia?

Comment: Yes, that is Julia. I'll type up a more detailed answer with some other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Other than C-based languages like C++ and Objective-C I know of no languages where you can straight up use C include headers and then call C functions directly. Many languages make interfacing with C pretty easy however:

Of the best I know are:

- [D](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html): `extern (C) double sin(double arg);` then `sin(0.5)`
- [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html): `from libc.math cimport sin` then `sin(0.5)`
- [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/): `t = ccall( (:clock, "libc"), Int32, ())`

2021 update:

- [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.53.0/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code): `extern "C" { fn sin(input: f64) -> f64; }` then `sin(0.5)` in an `unsafe` context.
- [Go with cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) actually allows exactly what was asked, importing `.h`-header files and calling code from them directly. See link for details. Was probably the correct answer even back in 2014.
- [Zig](https://ziglearn.org/chapter-4/#cimport): `const c = @cImport({ @cInclude("math.h"); });` then `c.sin(0.5)`

Comment: If my memory serves right you can add Rust and Zig to the list.